# Validate Registry Keys with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell

Trying to create a function that validates values in the registry editor. The script works fine unless I am trying to find values of 2 different properties with the same path. For example, if you comment out the second HKLM path, the script works... but if you leave it in, the script will not work because there is a duplicate path ("HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hyperkbd"). What is the workaround for this?

```bsh
function validate-registry{

    $registrylist = 

    @{ 

    "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hyperkbd" = "ErrorControl","0";
    "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hyperkbd" = "Start","3";

     }

    foreach ($registry in $registrylist.Keys)
    { 
        $namevaluearray = $registrylist[$registry]
        $name = $namevaluearray[0]
        $value = $namevaluearray[1]

        if( 
        (Get-ItemProperty $registry -name $name).($name) -eq $value )

        {

        write-host $name "is set to the correct value."

        }
        else
        { 

        write-host "The value of" $namevaluearray "is INCORRECT."

        }

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use nested hashtables to store 1-to-many relationships:

```bsh
function Validate-Registry {

    $registrylist = @{
        "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hyperkbd" = @{
            "ErrorControl" = "0"
            "Start" = "3"
        }
    }

    foreach ($registry in $registrylist.Keys) { 
        foreach($valueName in $registrylist[$registry].Keys){
            $value = $registrylist[$registry][$valueName]

            if ((Get-ItemPropertyValue -LiteralPath $registry -Name $valueName) -eq $value)
            {
                write-host $valueName "is set to the correct value."
            }
            else { 
                write-host "The value of" $valueName "is INCORRECT."
            }
        }
    } 
}
```